# Why does Facebook suggest adding the event code for their tracking pixel outside of the <head> tag/what effect does this have?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm adding a Facebook tracking script for a client and noticed that the instructions say to add a section of the code *just below* the closing head tag (before the body). However standard practice suggests that all scripts should be loaded at the end of the body, while tracking code like Google Analytics suggests that you add them in the head so it triggers right away. What effect does adding a script between the head and body tags have (page load, data collection, etc.), and why does Facebook specifically just want the event code outside of the head tag? How is it different from adding it as the last item in the head tag?

Instructions (not sure if any part of the initiation script contains data specific to my client, so blurring the whole thing for privacy):

[image: Image of instructions]

Comment: Well, one effect would be to violate the [html5 content model for the `<html>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element). Seems like a weird recommendation.

Comment: Right, and that's the only information I could find from the research I did; that it's bad.

Comment: I would inform them about that as it seems to be a really wrong advice...

Comment: what's the URL where you see that example?

Comment: @AhmedMasud Unfortunately, I was only sent a couple screenshots along with the code itself, but it looks like it appears as part of the code creation/registration process.

Answer (score 3):

that's a typo.  See [Facebook Pixel Implementation Guide](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/952192354843755)

> Your website's original code: Paste the Facebook pixel code **between the <head> and </head>**<sup>1</sup> tags of your web page. You may already have other existing code between the head tags, so just place the pixel code underneath that, but above </head>.

<sup>1</sup> Bold added by me.

Comment: Well that's a huge typo indeed, with a warning "be sure not to place it inside the head tags" and a code example supporting that... such an advice indeed seems strange.

Comment: @LaurentS. I was just about to comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a typo. I think they're assuming you're putting the whole pixel code on in the  tag affecting every page on your site and only want you to add the conversion script on the page you need it to load on. If you are editing just that page, there shouldn't be an issue with sticking that script in the head.